# OData EDM Missing Property

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

Using the generic northwind service for OData V4 we are able to make this query:

```
http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$expand=Orders($expand=Order_Details)
```

This utilizes a double expand and returns the correct json. In my metadata file,
first order expands are possible, but whenever I use the second expand in parenthesis I get the error:

```
The EDM instance of type '[Microsoft.Dynamics.DataEntities.XX Nullable=True]' is missing the property 'YY'.
```

where XX and YY are different entities in the form given above:
.../ZZ?$expand=XX($expand=YY)

I checked the navigation properties in the metadata repeatedly and they are all spelled correctly and inputted correctly under the correct categories. Does anyone have any idea why it keeps complaining that the property is missing?

Answer (score 1):

From your question what I understood: you are trying to retrieve ZZ entity records including collection valued navigation properties of XX entity, recursively another collection valued navigation properties of YY entity.

In other words, all Customers with their Orders with their Order details.

Atleast what am aware of, viz Dynamics CRM webapi evolution starts from v8.0 thru v9 today, the supported operations, functions, actions enhanced a lot. But I afraid what you are expecting is not supported yet (I am also curious if someone prove me wrong so I can learn.) [Read the latest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/query-data-web-api#bkmk_expandRelated).

If you read the above documentation, you have other option - **fetchxml** which can be still used with web api requests.

Sample query to get 5 Accounts + their Tasks:

```
GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/accounts?$top=5&$select=name&$expand=Account_Tasks($select=subject,scheduledstart)
```

Try adding some properties (`$select` attributes) in `$expand` & see if it works.

Comment: Hey Arun, you are correct. Expand is not supported beyond one level. The support may come in future, but there is no timeline yet.